# firefox not preserving the home page settings after restart

Tags: firefox

Whenever I change the Firefox homepage from *yahoo.com* (`about:config`, enter new address in list), the changes are not preserved when I restart Firefox.

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the home page from `about:config`? And what property are you modifying exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , Firefox have provided a Guide for you.

It consists of several cases that can cause the issue you got.

The problem seems to appear due to user don't have enough permissions to save his settings to  `prefs.js` file. so locate the file and change the permissions to the file as

to locate the file

```
locate prefs.js
```

then you will get some output similar to this

```
/home/jai/.mozilla/firefox/gvj89mfl.default/prefs.js
```

take the firefox prefs.js path from your home folder.

then

```
chmod 755  <path to prefs.js file>
```

will resolve your issue.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-fix-preferences-wont-save#w_unable-to-save-any-preferences-or-settings

Comment: Hi Rajagenupula, hi Andrea, thanks for your messages. After changing the prefs.js file (there were no further prefs1,2,3.js files to be deleted) the changes could still be redone - the redo button was still active. @Rajgenupula: what precisely do you mean by locate the file (I found it's folder)? How can I change permissions? Where do I apply chmod 755  <path to prefs.js file>? Thank you in advance Kulalila

Comment: @Kulalila have updated my answer.